# creating php backend to fill forms with captcha

Tags: php, curl

I was writing the backend for an app that allows students in my university to login to their ids and view information . but I cannot get the captcha to work .. when i try to access the captcha url using a cURL script it returns a random string (same everytime) .. how do I
display the captcha and allow the students to login ?

i am just accessing the university's website here is my code

```
<?php
$url   = 'https://academics.vit.ac.in/student/captcha.asp';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
$open = curl_exec($ch);
$er = curl_errno($ch);
echo $er;
?>
```

and the output i am getting with the header is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Pragma: no-cache Content-Type: image/bmp Expires: Thu, 08            May 2014 14:00:31 GMT Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0 Content-Disposition: inline; filename=captcha.bmp         Set-Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDCAWSBBSA=LNEPDIEBDCJINKGOAHOGLFCE; secure; path=/ X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date:    Thu, 08 May 2014 14:01:30 GMT Connection: close BM" >(‚äßþÿ…0    

BM" >(‚äßþÿ…0      // this is the  output content .. the content type is already set to image/bmp
```

any ideas how can i get this captcha ?

Comment: get curl to duplicate exactly what your browser is doing when you hit the same url. preserve the state of that request between your users' visits, so that when the user submits their stuff to your server, your server can recreate the original request/cookies to the captcha server, blah blah blah. basically set up a full-blown proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some web service for the captchas? Check their documentation, without any more information I can guess the random string is probably the image itself that you need to either save to a file to server it or send it directly to the client by setting a header for the filetype and printing the content.

**Edit:**
So yes, it is returning the file itself, if you want to serve it yourself try something like this:

```
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
header("Content-type: image/bmp");
echo $content;
```

But, are you sure that's what you want to do? you could just serve the image directly by using the url in your html:

```
<img src="https://academics.vit.ac.in/student/captcha.asp" />
```

Comment: thanks .. it works now :) .. but if i use the secong option how do i store the cookies that come with the captcha into a file to be sent back by curl .. when i make the post request to the page as they will be stored in browser cookies?? . or is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: Oh, if you have to grab the cookies then you just have to grab the image and serve it yourself the way you are doing now.